# Microsoft Outlook 2010 doesn't remember BPOS password

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have a BPOS account and Outlook was set up for this account by the Microsoft Online Sign-in application. If the Sign-in application isn't open and I open Outlook, it always asks me for the account's password, even if I tell it to remember it. This doesn't happen if I have the Sign-in application open.

Is there a way to make Outlook not ask for the password when the Sign-in application isn't open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According Microsoft's BPOS representatives no. I tried to get this functionality right after we switched.  According to the documentation in the coming Microsoft Live 365, which is the maturation of BPOS, this functionality will be default. The time frame for this move is this calendar year according to MS, but your company may differ.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! Guess I'll have to wait for my account to be upgraded.